# keymapping when ssh-ing from mac to linux

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, key-binding

I'm using Lion to ssh -X to a linux machine and work on some code thats located on it. I open up an editor on the remote machine (usually matlab) and program on it.

My problem is that in the linux there is no concept of the command key. So if I want to copy some text from a local window to the editor that runs on the remote, I need to to command-c to copy, and then control-v to paste. This obviously drives me nuts.

I was wondering if there is a way to change the keymapping such that the command key will be recognized as a control key on the remote processes. Or is this something I need to change on my local (mac) X configuration?